# Convert xls files to csv files in apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, converters, dataflow, processor

Hello guys I'm trying to convert .xls files to .csv in apache NIFI data flow. I tried many solutions with no result I even tried creating a script like this [sccript](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/where-to-convert-xls-file-to-csv-file-inside-Nifi-data-flow/m-p/112430)

Thank you in advance

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Particularly unclear in this question: "many solutions", "no result" - doesn't give us a hint on what you did, what you put in, what you got out of it, what you expected. You might want to try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your `ExecuteStreamCommand` as

[image: xls-to-csv]

and try using below code in your python script,

```
import csv
import os
import sys
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pandas import ExcelFile

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=sys.stdin.read(),logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8',engine='xlrd')

#flowfile_content = ExcelFile(BytesIO(sys.stdin.read()))
#excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(flowfile_content, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')

csv_data_rows = []
header_list = list(excel_file_df.columns.values)
temp_header_list = []

for field in header_list:
    temp = '"' + field +  '"'
    temp_header_list.append(temp)

header_row  = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in temp_header_list])
csv_data_rows.append(header_row)
is_header_row = True
for index, row in excel_file_df.iterrows():

    if is_header_row :
        is_header_row = False
        continue

    temp_data_list = []
    for item in row :
        #item = item.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        if hasattr(item, 'encode'):
            item = item.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

        item = str(item)
        item = item.replace('\n', '')
        item = item.replace('",', '" ')
        if item == 'nan':
            item=''
        temp = '"' + str(item) + '"'
        temp_data_list.append(temp)

    data_row = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in temp_data_list])
    data_row = data_row
    csv_data_rows.append(data_row)

for item in csv_data_rows:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\r\n" % item)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I got this error

Comment: TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes

Comment: There's no `startsWith` in the above code, did you change something? In any case, you can change bytes to a string with `decode("utf-8")`

Comment: that's exacty the problem there's no startsWith in code and I don't know why

Comment: I think the problem is in xlrd library

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-poi-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.poi.ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor/index.html)? If so and it didn't work can you share any errors, logs, etc.?

Comment: Yes I tried but this processor don't convert only xlsx files and not xls I'm trying to use ExecuteStreamCommand to run a python script and I'm getting an error saying sys.stdin is bytes and not str

Comment: stdin is the flow file

Answer (score 0):

```
    import csv
import os
import io
import sys
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pandas import ExcelFile
import petl as etl

#xls = etl.fromxls(sys.stdin)
#wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=xls,logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w', encoding='utf-8'))
excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(sys.stdin.buffer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8',engine='xlrd')

#flowfile_content = ExcelFile(BytesIO(sys.stdin.read()))
#excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(flowfile_content, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')

csv_data_rows = []
header_list = list(excel_file_df.columns.values)
temp_header_list = []

for field in header_list:
    temp = '"' + field +  '"'
    temp_header_list.append(temp)

header_row  = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in temp_header_list])
csv_data_rows.append(header_row)
is_header_row = True
for index, row in excel_file_df.iterrows():

    if is_header_row :
        is_header_row = False
        continue

    temp_data_list = []
    for item in row :
        #item = item.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        if hasattr(item, 'encode'):
            item = item.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')

        item = str(item)
        item = item.replace('\n', '')
        item = item.replace('",', '" ')
        if item == 'nan':
            item=''
        temp = '"' + str(item) + '"'
        temp_data_list.append(temp)

    data_row = ','.join([str(elem) for elem in temp_data_list])
    data_row = data_row
    csv_data_rows.append(data_row)

for item in csv_data_rows:
    sys.stdout.write("%s\r\n" % item)
```